# How can I pretty print the arguments' float default value in python 2.x?

Tags: python, floating-point, format

Give follow python function define:

```
def Foo(a=0.1, b=1.6):
    pass
```

when I call *'help(Foo)'*, I will get:

```
Help on function Foo in module __main__:
Foo(a=0.10000000000000001, b=1.6000000000000001)
```

But I wish get:

```
Help on function Foo in module __main__:
Foo(a=0.1, b=1.6)
```

dear all of you, is there a way to print this pretty?

Comment: You would rather it be pretty than correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2.7, this happens by default.

```
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> def Foo(a=0.1, b=1.6):
    pass

>>> help(Foo)
Help on function Foo in module __main__:

Foo(a=0.1, b=1.6)
```

In earlier versions of Python, there is no easy way to change this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I can think of as a workaround for earlier versions:

```
def float_prettifier(digits):
    formatter = '%%.%df' % digits
    class pretty_float(float):
        def __str__(self): return formatter % self
        __repr__ = __str__
    return pretty_float

def Foo(a = float_prettifier(1)(0.1), b = float_prettifier(1)(1.6)): pass

help(Foo)
```